# сохранить данные в тхт не построчно

Tags: c#

Есть такой код, который сохраняет текст в тхт построчно...

```
private static void Save(string data)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("data.txt", true, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
        writer.Write(data + Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

но мне нужно чтобы он сохранялся через пробел в одну строку
вместо

1
2
3

=>должно быть так: 1 2 3

Comment: замени _Environment.NewLine_ на пробел

Comment: @Grundy ok,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно должно быть так:

```
private static void Save(string data)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("data.txt", true, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
    writer.Write(data + " ");
    writer.Close();
}
```

`Environment.NewLine` заменить на пробел.